# Sphinx substitution with a container

Tags: containers, python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext

How can I substitute a container directive ? The following doesn't work:

```
.. |sub| container::

    Some text here

    .. image:: img/some_image.png

    Some other text here
```

The error message is

```
WARNING: Substitution definition "sub" empty or invalid.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. ReST substitutions apply to inline text (single paragraphs), but a container is a block element.

And if you try

```
.. |sub| replace:: container::

    Some text here

    .. image:: img/some_image.png

    Some other text here
```

you will get

```
ERROR: Error in "replace" directive: may contain a single paragraph only.
```

You could work around this by putting the container in a separate file and pull it in to the master file using `.. include::`.