# How to use substitution definitions with code blocks?

Tags: python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext

I tried using substitution definitions together with code blocks in Sphinx documentation however it doesn't work. This is my ReST source code:

```
.. |foo| code-block:: python

   foo = 1

|foo|
```

Sphinx throws the following errors:

```
/.../examples.rst:184: WARNING: Substitution definition "foo" empty or invalid.

.. |foo| code-block:: python

   foo = 1

/.../examples.rst:193: ERROR: Undefined substitution referenced: "foo".
```

How can I make this example work?

---

- **Sphinx version:** 1.5.5 (using Sphinx 1.6.2 the above error transforms into a warning).

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/8789408/407651

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible without changing `code-block`.
I have created a Sphinx extension which provides `substitution-code-block` for this purpose.

It allows you to define `substitutions` in `conf.py` and then use these substitutions in `.. substitution-code-block` blocks.

This extension is at https://github.com/adamtheturtle/sphinx-substitution-extensions.

However, this is a very small amount of code.
To enable this in your own codebase without a third party extension, create a module in your codebase with the following contents:

```py
"""
Custom Sphinx extensions.
"""

from typing import List

from sphinx.application import Sphinx
from sphinx.directives.code import CodeBlock


class SubstitutionCodeBlock(CodeBlock):  # type: ignore
    """
    Similar to CodeBlock but replaces placeholders with variables.
    """

    def run(self) -> List:
        """
        Replace placeholders with given variables.
        """
        app = self.state.document.settings.env.app
        new_content = []
        self.content = self.content  # type: List[str]
        existing_content = self.content
        for item in existing_content:
            for pair in app.config.substitutions:
                original, replacement = pair
                item = item.replace(original, replacement)
            new_content.append(item)

        self.content = new_content
        return list(CodeBlock.run(self))


def setup(app: Sphinx) -> None:
    """
    Add the custom directives to Sphinx.
    """
    app.add_config_value('substitutions', [], 'html')
    app.add_directive('substitution-code-block', SubstitutionCodeBlock)
```

Then, use this module the `extensions` defined in `conf.py`.
Then, set the `substitutions` variable in `conf.py` e.g. to `[('|foo|', 'bar')]` to replace `|foo|` with `bar` in every `substitution-code-block`.